# heatmap in ggplot, different color for each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, heatmap

I am trying to produce a heatmap in ggplot. I want each group to have different color gradient, but don't know how to do that. My current code looks like this:

```
## dummy data -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
data <- data.frame(
  group = sample(c("Direct Patient Care", "Indirect Patient Care", "Education", "Rounds", "Handoff", "Misce"), 30, replace = T),
  pct = rnorm(30, mean = 50, sd = 8)
)

## generate group id 
data <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

data$grpid <- with(data, ifelse(group == "Direct Patient Care", 1, ifelse(group == "Indirect Patient Care", 2,
                                                                        ifelse(group == "Education", 3, 
                                                                               ifelse(group == "Rounds", 4,
                                                                                      ifelse(group == "Handoff", 5,6 ))))))

## draw graph ------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                           
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=id, y=group, fill = pct)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"), aspect.ratio = 0.4) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )+
  # guides(fill = guide_legend("Time, %")) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_x_continuous (name = " ", breaks = seq(1, 8, by = 1)) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = " ") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,hjust = 1,vjust = 1), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5) ) +
  ggtitle("Heatmap of time spent doing activities across 194 shifts")


p + scale_fill_gradient2(low = "white", high = "red", limits = c(0, 80), breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70), guide = guide_legend("Time, %"))  ## change the color theme ##
```

And the resulting figure looks like this:
[image]

How can I change the color theme for each group, like red for 'Rounds', blue for 'Misce', green for 'Handoff' etc...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own rescaled value in your data and then slightly "hacking" the `alpha` aesthetic combined with the `fill` aesthetic:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rescale = scales::rescale(pct)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = factor(id), y = group)) +
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = rescale, fill = group), color = "white") +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.1, 1))
```

First we create a new column called `rescale` which `rescales` the `pct` from `0` to `1` then you force the `scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1))` [note, in this case I used `c(0.1, 1)` so that you can still "see" the zero points.

Finally, you probably want to remove the guides:

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rescale = scales::rescale(pct)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = factor(id), y = group)) +
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = rescale, fill = group), color = "white") +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.1, 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: Plot]

*N.B. by using `aes(x = factor(id)...` you can get around manually setting your `x-axis` since in this case it appears you want to treat it as a factor not a numeric scale.*

Finally, if you really want to get fancy, you could double-encode the `axis.text.y` colors to that of the levels of your `factor` (i.e., `data$group`) variable:

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rescale = scales::rescale(pct)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = factor(id), y = group)) +
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = rescale, fill = group), color = "white") +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.1, 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = scales::hue_pal()(length(levels(data$group)))),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "", y = "")
```

[image: Fancy Plot]

Comment: Thanks, Jason, this is very helpful!! Is there a way to keep the color bar for each group with the same cutoffs I showed in my figure?

Comment: @mandy you can probably get close by changing the `mutate(...)` line to `mutate(rescale = floor(pct / 10) * 10)` -- I'm pretty sure that `ggplot2` somewhat discourages this type of plot and aesthetic mapping which is why it feels like you're jumping through hoops. Your original plot is, arguably, easier to interpret with only one color mapping. Said differently, is "Dark Teal" more or less intense than "Dark Orange"? While I am by no means an expert in human computer interaction / visualization, those subtleties can misguide the end-user / consumer of your plots.