# How create a heatmap for different columns separately?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a dataset which shows groups and 3 numeric variables. I want to create a plot, which shows heatmaps (+values inside the cell) for each of the column separately. The left/right axis labels should be values from variable group, while top/bottom should be variable names.
I found something similar to what I am looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338361/heatmap-in-ggplot-different-color-for-each-group), however it is row wise rather than column wise.

```
df<-structure(list(group = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), 
    mean_eur = c(-129.567230632235, -22.2194324821243, 1342.96054365896, 
    -902.330543160851, -1489.68836579957, 927.850034173604, 0.0678674942780786
    ), mean_eur_abs = c(723.928762243989, 3769.9065702668, 6117.92527832234, 
    4047.2805615705, 6057.02130927563, 4124.27784143031, 5717.03080420487
    ), nr_obs = c(1123, 12.7372802960222, 16.3672687465791, 15.9754010695187, 
    16.4488279016581, 16.0794132524026, 13.343143812709)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I undersand well, maybe something like this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral")), space="Lab")

m <- reshape2::melt(df)
ggplot(data =m, aes(
  x = variable,
  y = group,
  fill = value
)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        text = element_text(size=16))+
  theme_minimal(base_family = "serif")
```

[image]

or 3 different graph arranged column wise:

```
graph <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {
  sub <- m[m$variable==colnames(df)[i+1],]
  graph[[i]] <- ggplot(data =sub, aes(
    x = variable,
    y = group,
    fill = value
  )) +
    geom_tile() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
          text = element_text(size=16))+
    theme_minimal(base_family = "serif")
}
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(graph[[1]],graph[[2]],graph[[3]],ncol=3)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for examples, however I am looking to something similar to you first plot (no column wise division of variable in the plot) and at the same time similar to the second one (it shows different values for each of the columns while in the first plot they are perceived together)

Comment: probably the easiest way is to normalize the columns of the data frame to have the same range (i.e. from 0 to 1). `norm <- function(x)(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))`
`df[,-1] <- apply(df[,-1], 2, norm)`